# Android - Correct way of notifications and a Service

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, kotlin, android-notifications

I'm working on an Android APP that has to keep a connection via Bluetooth and listen to incoming calls, if it is running in the foreground or not.
I was able to get it working by keeping a Service running when I got the Bluetooth connection and stopping it when disconnected. The `Service`:

```
public class ConnectionService extends Service {

    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 327;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //Creates notification
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        //Makes service run in foreground
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

My question is: **Considering changes on how notifications work and that I don't really understand how it worked and how it is working now, which is the correct way of creating a notification?

And still, considering what I'm trying to get with this Service, do you have any comment whether it's good or bad?**

Thanks to all.
*The code presented is in Java, but now I'm working with Kotlin, so both languages are accepted.